# How to create chip select functionality for SK9822 addressable LEDs

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, spi

I want to connect some SK9822 LEDs to an SPI bus that is already in use. As these LEDs do not have a chip select, I need to make one.

Is it just as simple as an npn transistor (BC547 perhaps)? Feed the chip select signal from microcontroller to the base, the collector to the microcontroller clock and the emitter to the first LED clock input?

Does this work this way and, if not, what is the correct way?

Comment: "the" correct way? A correct way is any way that gets the correct signal to the LEDs.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/359672/17178

Comment: but the proper way is probably to use an AND logic ic.